# How can I fix a string in shell script (remove

Tags: string, shell, parsing, awk, sed

I am webscraping a cablemodem's HTML diagnostics page source code using shell script and I need to fix some coding errors that were done by Motorola. There are a few occurrences in many pages that are missing the closing `>` at the end of an input tag which kind of breaks the thing. Since the value preceding the `</td>` is dynamic, I need to be able to dynamically fix the tag.

Example string:
`<td bgcolor=#E7DAAC width=138 colspan=2><input type="text" name="NumberOfCpes" size="3" maxlength="3" value=253 </td>`

See how it ends by `value=253 </td>`

How can I replace that space by a ">" for every occurrence in the whole page? Keep in mind that there are other places where a `</td>` is preceded by a space in these pages so `sed 's/ <\/td>/><\/td>/g'` will not work correctly.

Thanks for your help

Comment: do you need to support things like `<td name="<ugly_with_brace_in_name">` ? If no, you can do something like `s/<(.*)</<\1/></g`, i.e. two opening `<`'s = `</><`

Comment: @TomaszLewowski It should be `s/<([^<*])</<\1></g` since the `*` matches greedy.

Comment: @hek2mgl thanks for the correction

Comment: @hek2mgl @TomaszLewowski
cat temp.html | sed 's/<([^<*])</<\1></g'
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
Am I missing something?

Comment: @vizi0n You need to use `sed -r ...` or escape the parentheses. Also check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not well formed HTML it should not break your tools - if you are using the right tools.

To parse HTML you need to use a DOM parser. I suggest to use XPath along with it. From the command line on Linux you can use `xmllint` which is part of the package `libxml2-utils`. The DOM parser available trough `libxml2` (the common xml library on Linux) can parse the above, invalid input.

Let's say you want to extract the input value:

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//input[@name="NumberOfCpes"]/@value' test.html
```

It reports an HTML parse error which you can redirect to `/dev/null`:

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//input[@name="NumberOfCpes"]/@value' test.html 2>/dev/null
```

but still gives you the right value on stdout:

```
value="253"
```

However, of course it is annoying that the site produces invalid HTML at all.

Comment: Maybe I did not express myself well by saying "parsing". I either grab bits of info in the source code or dumped HTML output from lynx by using grep and sed I find what I need. This broken tag causes lynx to display an empty input box on the dumped output. The DOM parser might seem overkill to me, at least on a short-term basis. But I will look into that for some learning later on. Thanks

Comment: LOL! You are using Lynx and say a DOM parser (like xmllint) is overhead?! How does lynx parse the HTML? Magic?

Comment: I'm using either wget or lynx to grab the HTML source from the modem, or straight lynx if I just need to dump the browser output. Some information I need is not in specific tags, just plain text so I use grep, sed and cut alot. Maybe parsing is not the right term for what I do.

Answer (score 0):

An regex and substitution approach with sed

```
sed -r 's#(<input[^>]+)[[:space:]]*<#\1>#g;s#[[:space:]]+([>])#\1#g'
```

example if you have below

```
<td bgcolor=#E7DAAC width=138 colspan=2><input type="text" name="NumberOfCpes" size="3" maxlength="3" value=253       </td>
```

your output will be

```
<td bgcolor=#E7DAAC width=138 colspan=2><input type="text" name="NumberOfCpes" size="3" maxlength="3" value=253>/td>`
```